# R: Creating multiple dataframes based on row filter

Tags: r

I have a dataframe`(df)` that looks like below:

```
  Date           Group       Value
01-04-2029      Saffron      62.78
01-04-2029      Green        75.65
01-05-2019      Saffron      67.89
01-06-2019      Saffron      54.56
01-06-2019      Green        77.00
01-07-2019      Green        71.22
```

Objective: I want to create two seperate dataframes based on `Group`. Essentially I am looking for the followings

```
df_saffron: 
    Date           Group       Value
01-04-2029        Saffron      62.78
01-05-2019        Saffron      67.89
01-06-2019        Saffron      54.56

df_green:
   Date           Group        Value
01-04-2029        Green        75.65
01-06-2019        Green        77.00
01-07-2019        Green        71.22
```

Specifically, if I use the following code snippet ([this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180753/create-multiple-data-frames-from-one-based-off-values-with-a-for-loop))

```
for(i in unique(as.character(df$Group))) {
    nam <- paste("df", i, sep = ".")
    assign(nam, df[df$Group==i,])
    }
```

I am not getting any dataframe like `df.Green` or `df.Saffron`. I mean I am getting

```
<0 rows> (or 0 -length row.names)
```

I have also taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679034/filter-loop-to-create-multiple-data-frames) SO thread, but I am getting errors.

```
Error in assign(as.character(v, data %>% filter(data$Group == v), envir = .GlobalEnv)) :
argument "value" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I am novice to R and thus asking for any clue on where I am missing out?

Comment: Your code is working for me, and it gives the right `df.Green` and `df.Saffron`. It might help if you turn the `Group` column into strings with `as.character()` first (I guess they are factors). The best way to share data on StackOverflow is to use `dput()`, so we get exactly the same data frame you are looking at.

Comment: Are you sure you have a dataframe and not matrix. The error message gives a hint. What is `class(df)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah: The class of the data is dataframe. Sorry I forgot to mention that I had converted the data to `as.data.frame(df)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shoudl do it:

```
for (v in unique(df$Group)){

  tmp <- subset(df, Group == v)
  assign(paste0('df_', tolower(v)), tmp)

}
```

I always find it easier to create a temporary dataset first rather than squash it all into the 1 assign step

Comment: I am getting error as `Error in assign(paste0("data.", tolower(v), tmp)) : 
  argument "value" is missing, with no default`

Comment: your bracket is in the wrong spot. Use  assign(paste0("data.", tolower(v)), tmp)

Comment: Well, that bracket was a typo. Sorry for the same. Even if I use the same, I am not able to get `df.green` or `df.saffron`

Comment: well there must be something else going on then with your data structure because it works fine for me, sorry. please add the `dput()` of your dat to the question and the exact code you are using (cop/paste it so there are no typos)

Answer (score 4):

Use `split` :

```
list_data <- split(df, df$Group)
```

This will give you list of dataframes, if you need separate dataframes.

```
names(list_data) <- paste0("df_", names(list_data))
list2env(list_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

To show how you can transform `for` loop code to `lapply`.

This is `for` loop code :

```
for(i in unique(as.character(df$Group))) {
   nam <- paste("df", i, sep = ".")
   assign(nam, df[df$Group==i,])
   #More code
   #More code
   #More code
}
```

To change it to `lapply` :

```
lapply(split(df, df$Group), function(x) {
   #More code
   #More code
   #More code
})
```

You can infact also use `by` which does not require data to be splitted.

```
by(df, df$Group, function(x) {
    #More code
    #More code
    #More code
})
```

Instead of accessing data in `df_green`, `df_saffron` in `for` loop you can access it in `x` in `lapply`/`by`.

Comment: Actually the idea is to perform some operations on each dataframe on the fly.Hence may be `for` loop is needed?

Comment: There are other(better) ways to perform operations on list of dataframes (eg. `lapply`) but difficult to comment on it without knowing details about what you want to do on each dataframe.

Comment: @pythondumb No, use the splitted df's and `lapply` the data transformation.

Comment: @Rui: Can you please little elaborate?

Comment: @RonakShah: I am trying to run a time series model on each of the dataframe

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how you can change `for` loop code to `lapply` or `by`.

Comment: @RonakShah: Thanks for the same. I have already used the one which you have shown in the second block. But when I am trying to see the `df.Green` or `df.Saffron` the error is coming as `<0 rows> (or 0 -length row.names) `.

Comment: @RonakShah: `class(df)` is `data.frame`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by RonakShah, I have tried the following:

```
temp < -NULL
for (i in unique(as.character(Group)){
    nam <- paste("df", i, sep = ".")
    assign(nam, df[df$Group==i,])
   # more code
   result <- data.frame(Date = dates_all,
                        Group = i,
                        Value = all_values,
                        Derived = der_vals) 
   }
 temp <-result
 final <-rbind(temp,result)
```

But the final `dataframe` looks like

```
      Date           Group       Value     Derived
    01-04-2029      Saffron      62.78      22
    01-04-2029      Saffron      75.65      34.46
    01-05-2019      Saffron      67.89      54
    01-06-2019      Saffron      54.56      78
    01-06-2019      Saffron      77.00      29.85
    01-07-2019      Saffron      71.22      45.67
```

In other words, only `Saffron` as Group is getting repeated, although the derived values are correct ones. 
Can any body help on this?